# Segmentation fault when copying the value from an array element to an integer pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, initialization, function-definition

I was writing a test code in C and came across something which didn't make sense. I have an array of integers and whenI try to copy (value of) one of those elements to an integer pointer (i.e. int*), I get segfault. The segmentation fault is coming from integer pointers because if I use a regular integer (instead of int*), then there is no segmentation fault. I am trying to figure out why am I getting a segmentation fault for storing an integer value like `*max = arr[0]`.

Can someone clarify why it is seg faulting? The logic behind the code will seem absurd because I am trying to learn about pointers, so please ignore my reasoning for the code. I just need to figure out the reasoning for seg fault.

```
    int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
      int arr[] = {1000, 11, 445, 1, 330, 3000};
    
      int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

      int *min;
      int *max;
      
      // Please ignore the reasoning behind this comparison since
      // it is simply a test code in progress.
      // My goal is to find out why this assignment is seg faulting
      if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
        *max = arr[0];      <----Seg fault here. 
        *min = arr[1];
      }else {
        *min = arr[0];
        *max = arr[1];
      }
    
      // Calculate min and max in array and stores those values in `min` and `max`
      calculateMinMax (arr, len, min, max); 

      printf("Min Value:%d", *min);
      printf("Max Value:%d", *max);
    
      return 0;
    }
```

Result in GDB

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555552bf in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe208) at minmaxarray.c:32
32      *max = arr[0];
(gdb)
```

Comment: Those are unintialised pointers. You need to point/set them to some valid memory before dereferencing them.

Comment: Maybe what you really meant was `max = &arr[0]`.

Comment: You never take a reference to the array values. Try using `&arr[0]` instead of `arr[0]` to get a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

When you work with pointers, you always have to keep in mind the distinction between *the pointer itself*, versus *the value that the pointer points to*.  And until you've set the pointer itself to point somewhere, the concept "the value that the pointer points to" is meaningless.

For a pointer variable `int *max`, when you say

```
max = ...
```

you're setting *the pointer itself*, and when you say

```
*max = ...
```

you're setting *the value that the pointer points to*.

But in the code you've posted, you've got lines like

```
*max = arr[0];
```

You're trying to set the value that the pointer points to, before you've set the pointer to point anywhere.  As I said, this is meaningless, and it tends to result in a segmentation fault or other such fatal error.

As others have posted, if you want `min` and `max` to point to the certain elements in the array, you want something like

```
max = &arr[0];
```

If you just wanted `*max` to *be* a value fetched from the array, that's what

```
*max = arr[0];
```

might do, but first, you'd have to make sure `max` pointed somewhere.  You could do

```
int temporary_storage_for_max;
max = &temporary_storage_for_max;
```

after which lines like

```
*max = arr[0];
```

would work.  But in that case, it would be silly to use pointers at all.  In that case, you might as well declare `max` as a plain int:

```
int max;
```

and then do things like

```
max = a[0];
```

But I'm guessing you do want `min` and `max` to be pointers, in which case, as mentioned,

```
max = &arr[0];
```

is the way to go.

Your `calculateMinMax` function probably needs work, too, but since you haven't shown that it's hard to say what it might need.  (Conceivably, if `calculateMinMax` does the min/max-finding work and does it properly, you don't need these initial assignments of `min` and `max` at all.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to assign `max` to `&arr[0]`, not the value of the first item in the array to the address in the pointer, as the pointer's value is currently undefined.

i.e.

```
   max = &arr[0];
   min = &arr[1];
```

etc.

Comment: Note that this will also require changes to `calculateMinMax()`.

Comment: It's non-obvious what that function does. OP probably wants to pass `&min` and `&max` so they an be written to (`int **` in both cases), but why the existing `if/else` block is needed as well as `calculateMinMax` is difficult to determine.

Comment: The `if/else` seems to set things up so the function can start scanning at index 2.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
  if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
    *max = arr[0];      <----Seg fault here. 
    *min = arr[1];
  }else {
    *min = arr[0];
    *max = arr[1];
  }
```

does not make a sense. The pointers `max` and `min` are not initialized. So dereferencing them invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover you have the function `calculateMinMax` that has to determine the maximum and minimum elements in the array.

So instead of the above code snippet just write

```
calculateMinMax (arr, len, &min, &max);
```

Pay attention to that you need to pass the pointers `min` and `max` to the function by reference through pointers to them. Otherwise the function will deal with copies of values of the pointers and changing the copies will not change the original pointers.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void calculateMinMax( const int a[], size_t n, int **min, int **max )
{
    *min = ( int * )a;
    *max = ( int * )a;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( **max < a[i] )
        {
            *max = ( int * )( a + i );
        }
        else if ( a[i] < **min )
        {
            *min = ( int * )( a + i );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateMinMax( const int a[], size_t n, int **min, int **max )
{
    *min = ( int * )a;
    *max = ( int * )a;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (**max < a[i])
        {
            *max = ( int * )( a + i );
        }
        else if (a[i] < **min)
        {
            *min = ( int * )( a + i );
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = { 1000, 11, 445, 1, 330, 3000 };

    size_t len = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] );

    int *min;
    int *max;

    calculateMinMax( arr, len, &min, &max );

    printf( "Min Value: %d\n", *min );
    printf( "Max Value: %d\n", *max );
}
```

The program output is

```
Min Value: 1
Max Value: 3000
```